# Dynamic Features: Split Install Error: -2

Tags: android

If you are trying to install a dynamic feature on a device with the following code:

```
SplitInstallManagerFactory.create(this).startInstall(request)
```

and get an error like `Split Install Error: -2` or `code -100`, then it seems that you are faced with some kind of google bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try to erase the data for the Google Play Market application in the settings of your device, and also reinstall the application containing the dynamic function to be installed. In my case, it helped.